# Is it possible to store information client-side?

Tags: javascript, php, ruby-on-rails, database, client-side

I'm pretty new to programming so I'm unsure if this is a stupid question or not, but is it possible to store information on the client side? Through JavaScript somehow?

For example say you wanted to create something basic like a to-do list or an alarm clock app. Would you need to use PHP or Rails or something to create that or is it possible to store that information on the client-side? If so would I use JavaScript?

Comment: Look at HTML5 Local storage: http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Comment: while possible, generally not a good idea

Comment: @Dagon is it not a good idea due to security or is there another reasons as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep! You can use sessionStorage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

or localStorage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

to store data client-side. It's very easy to use too!

Comment: That's perfect! So localStorage seems like a great idea for simple things but does it have limitations? Would it be a bad idea (or even possible) to create a user base with a username/password using localStorage?

Comment: Yes, since it's client-side, if the user clears his cache, the data will be deleted. It's a pretty horrible idea to create a user base with local storage due to that fact :P. You'd want to look into databases for that.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! Does localStorage also work if I use Phonegap/Cordova to put it onto android? And their data would then be erased if they deleted their phone browsers cache?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with HTML5 local storage, and cookies.

Answer (score 1):

I you wish to store information locally you can do so at the variable `localSotrage`.

To write information use:

```
localStorage.setItem(name, value);
```

To read information use:

```
localStorage.getItem(name); //Returns item value
```

To remove information use:

```
localStorage.setItem(name);
```

Keep in mind that `localStorage` stores information **across the whole domain**. For example, if you store the variable *potato* at *www.mydomain.com/main*, then you can retrieve it at *www.mydomain.com/potato*.

I hope this helps you out.